# Upgrading kernel 2.6.18 to 2.6.32 on CentOS 5.10

Tags: centos, kernel, rpm, rpmbuild

I've been looking on Google for 4 hours and I can't find a solution to my problem.

I have a computer running CentOS 5.10 using Kernel 2.6.18-371.9.1.el5 and I would like to upgrade my kernel to 2.6.32 in order to run lxc (it need at least kernel 2.6.29).

I've been following this [HowTo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Custom_Kernel) and tried to install the 2.6.32 source package by typing:

```
[user@stag-devCentOS]$ rpm -i http://vault.centos.org/6.5/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.src.rpm 2>&1 | grep -v mock
```

I know it's the kernel for 6.5 version but I wasn't able to find a 2.6.32 kernel for CentOS 5.10.

When I'm running this command line, I get a md5 sum mismatch like this

```
[tanguy@stag-devCentos ~]$ rpm -i http://vault.centos.org/6.5/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.src.rpm 2>&1 | grep -v mock
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-xfer.ecr3WX: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID c105b9de
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /home/tanguy/rpmbuild/SOURCES/Makefile.common;53a94866: cpio: MD5 sum mismatch
```

I tried to add `--nomd5` and rebuild but it doesn't help.

I've tried a manual upgrade of the kernel, everything gone well until boot.
 i'm getting this error:

```
switchroot: mout failed: No such file or directory
Kernel panic - not syncing Attempted to kill init!
Pid: 1, comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32.27 #1
Call Trace:
[<ffffffff81041d3a>] ? panic+0x86/0x13d
[<ffffffff810c644e>] ? pcpu_chunk_relocate+0x10/0x6b
[<ffffffff810cb3db>] ? deactivate_super+0x20/0x77
[<ffffffff8104a66c>] ? exit_ptrace+0x20/0xee
[<ffffffff810448ae>] ? do_exit+0x72/0x633
[<ffffffff81044edc>] ? do_group-exit+0x6d/0x97
[<ffffffff81044f18>] ? sys_exit_group+0x12/0x16
[<ffffffff8100b96b>] ? system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b
```

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: can you add the error/warning in english again? but please don't post a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at `ELRepo`?  They have kernels from the 3.2 branch for EL5 (and therefore CentOS5) which should run `lxc`. It might save you having to compile! Have a look [here](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-lt).

Comment: Didn't know ElRepo, thanks, i'll read more about it and update my post if i succed.

Comment: Thanks sir, it worked flawless. I downloaded a 3.2.60-1.el5.elrepo kernel on Elrepo and installed it.