# Update Machine Kernel 2.6.18 with CentOS 5.4 to at least Kernel 2.6.31

Tags: centos, kernel

I have a CentOS machine with CentOS 5.4.

The installed kernel is 2.6.18-164.15.1.el5.centos.plus. We have a big amount of data inside the machine and we need to backup, the machine has a USB 3.0 connection but to make use of it we need to update kernel to at least version 2.6.31 (which is the first to support USB 3.0)

It seems to be possible with kernel-lt packages from el-repo as stated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138902/upgrading-kernel-2-6-18-to-2-6-32-on-centos-5-10), but, if you look at ELrepo the packages for EL5 are not there.

I have been looking in the internet and I found a place where the packages are available:

http://mirrors.coreix.net/elrepo-archive-archive/kernel/el5/x86_64/RPMS/

Either if I activate the el-repo repositories and I fire:

yum search kernel-lt

That search returns me the following packages:

kernel-lt.x86_64 : The Linux kernel. (The core of any Linux-based operating system.) kernel-lt-devel.x86_64 : Development package for building kernel modules to match the kernel. kernel-lt-doc.noarch : Various bits of documentation found in the kernel source. kernel-lt-headers.x86_64 : Kernel C header files for use by glibc.

When I tried to install that four packages with "yum install" the result is:
Nothing to do

I would be very proud if somebody can give me some light on how to do it.

Thanks for all in advance
Manuel Luis Aznar

Comment: In the repo you refer to, http://mirrors.coreix.net/elrepo-archive-archive/kernel/el5/x86_64/RPMS/,  I don't see any kernel 2.6 packages?

Comment: Hey there, I want to update kernel 2.6.18 (maximum allowed in CentOS/RHEL 5) to at least Kernel 2.6.31 which would give me USB 3.0 support...

Supposedly as I can see in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138902/upgrading-kernel-2-6-18-to-2-6-32-on-centos-5-10) that its possible with kernel-lt packages. If you go to this [link] (http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-lt) you will be able to find kernel-lt packages for CentOS 6 and 7 but NOT for CentOS 5.

I found the mirrors.coreix.net link looking by myself but dont know how to install...

If you can let me how, would be OK

Comment: You could download the kernel source for the most recent 2.6, and build the kernel yourself.  Otherwise, couldn't you backup over an network connection?

Comment: On the machine we are talking about...I had 40 TBytes to backup. Either downloadinfg the kernel source and building myself is risky if something goes wrong... and I was backing by network but its so slow at 1 Gbps...I calculate and its gonna take 2 months to get all data out...

Comment: I repeat: I see no 2.6.31 kernel on the coreix mirror.

Comment: Do you want to install the 3.2.87 from coreix mirror? There should be little risk in trying.

Comment: Hey there, @Gerard H. Pille you can download it from this [link](http://mirrors.coreix.net/elrepo-archive-archive/kernel/el5/x86_64/RPMS/)

In the end I installed the four packages and the kernel was installed, but in GRUB you have to press space to boot the installed kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I installed the four packages and the kernel was installed; but, in GRUB you have to press SPACE in order to boot the installed kernel.

I suppose you can change GRUB to boot the installed kernel too.

Comment: Manuel, what does "uname -a" give you now?

Comment: uname -a will give you information about the system: hostname, kernel, distribution, date in which the actual kernel was published and architecture

Comment: I know that, Manuel, but I was wondering what it gives you now.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=save
```

to

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

and then fire

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

This will make GRUB to boot the latest kernel by default.